# What prevents a toilet auger from fully extending into the toilet?

Tags: toilet, clog

I currently have a clog, and the plunger wasn't cutting it. I got [a 3' toilet auger](https://www.moen.ca/products/MLine/MLine_Toilet_auger/M7912), but I can only extend it about halfway in, even when trying to extend it further by cranking it clockwise.

What could be the cause for not being able to fully extend a toilet auger?

Answer (score 1):

You found the clog, and it's worse than you thought it was! A chlid's toy? bar of soap? Cell phone?